# How to update multiple key and values in dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Input:

```
lst  = {"scot":{"23", "poland"}, "martin":{"32", "england"},
        "":{"23", "ireland"},None:{"23", "indian"}, "1":{"", ""}}
```

Output:

```
lst2  = {"scot":{"230", "poland"}, "martin":{"320", "england"},
         "":{"230", "ireland"},None:{"230", "indian"}, "10":{"", ""}}
```

Code :

```
  for k,v in lst.items():
      if k is not None:
          if k.isdigit():
             k = k + "0"
             print(k)
      if v is not None and type(v) == set :
          for i in v:
             if i.isdigit():
                i =i + "0"
            print (i)
  print(lst)
```

But The values are not getting updated and I am getting below output:

```
{'scot': {'23', 'poland'}, 'martin': {'england', '32'}, '': {'23', 'ireland'}, None: {'23', 'indian'}, '1': {''}}
```

Comment: First of all `"1":{"", ""}` is going to resolve to `'1': {''}` on creation of your `dict` since `{"", ""}`  is a `set`.

Comment: You're changing the value of i and k, but not actually using it anywhere.  So you're not modifying the dictionary at all, just creating variables that isn't doing anything with the results (aside from printing them).

Comment: Also, you can't "change" the keys to a dictionary. You can only remove them and add new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track, but you were not updating the actual values in your dictionary. More importantly, you shouldn't be changing the iterables (dicts, sets, lists) while iterating through them - in the sense that you shouldn't be adding or removing new elements that would normally be part of the iteration (like add or remove key-value pairs while iterating through a dictionary).

Because of that, a simple implementation of your program needs to have two parts - first where you search your dictionary `lst` and record the necessary changes, and second where you implement those recorded changes.

Below code does just that,

```
lst = {"scot":{"23", "poland"}, "martin":{"32", "england"}, "":{"23", "ireland"},None:{"23", "indian"}, "1":{"", ""}}

keys_to_delete = []
kv_pairs_to_add = {}
ks_pairs_to_swap = []

# Collect what needs to change
for k,v in lst.items():
    if k is not None:
        if k.isdigit():
            # Save the old key for later deletion
            keys_to_delete.append(k)
            # Create and record the new entry
            kv_pairs_to_add[k + "0"] = v
            k += "0"
        print(k)
    # ------ Was this supposed to be v or k?
    if v is not None and type(v) == set:
        for i in v:
            if i.isdigit():
                # Record the key, old value, 
                # and new value as a sublist
                ks_pairs_to_swap.append([k, i, i+"0"])
                i += "0"
            print (i)

# Implement the changes
# Dictionary keys
for key in keys_to_delete:
    del lst[key]
lst.update(kv_pairs_to_add)

# Sets
for key, ov, nv in ks_pairs_to_swap:
    lst[key].remove(ov)
    lst[key].add(nv)

print(lst)
```

Note the comment with `------` - just checking if `v`there is not a bug, it seems your keys can be `None`, so the check should maybe be for `k` and not `v`.

Answer (score 0):

I never put the code into my IDE but looking at your code it does seem to be right but I noticed that you're not ACTUALLY updating your list, your only creating variable.

For example

```
for k,v in lst.items():
```

This creates two variables k,v and you use those variables in the for loop with if statements, in order to actually update it you'd have to figure out a way to remove the previous string and append the new updated variable k or v

In the if statement you're not actually appending and removing anything from the dictionary you are only adding something to k or v and printing the variable out.

I don't think I wrote this well, but I hope I gave you a possible clear understanding on why its not actually getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = {"scot": {"23", "poland"}, "martin": {"32", "england"}, "": {"23", "ireland"}, None: {"23", "indian"}, "1": {"", ""}}

result = {}
for k, v in lst.items():
    if k is not None or str:
        for i in v:
            if i.isdigit():
                i += "0"
            else:
                j = i
            result[k] = {i, j}
print(result)
```

Output:
{'scot': {'poland', '230'}, 'martin': {'england', "320"}, '': {'230', 'ireland'}, None: {'230', 'indian'}, '1': {''}}